# How to sell credits as products, using commerce module?

Tags: commerce

The ideas is to allow users to buy credits through Paypal etc. and only using that credits, they can buy 'real' products. I appreciate your hints to set this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Commerce Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_userpoints)* project. It allows to buy things using userpoints and there is also a feature that allows to buy userpoints that is based on a custom product type and rules, so fully customizable.

It most likely doesn't everything that you need, but it might be a start.

There is also [Commerce credits](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_credits) and more similar projects, but I haven't tried them out, no idea what exactly they do and how well they work.

*Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the Userpoints project and I was also involved in that project and still have some code lying around to re-work the UI and improve it.

Comment: Actually I found both modules badly lacking docs so I could not implement any. Can you please refer me to some basic tutorials?

Comment: me too the documentation was not there and thus difficult to implement

Comment: the credit is very bad module, really, It have some terrible bugs !!!

Comment: WHAT IS MEANING Setup the `decimal multiplicator` IN COMMERCE USERPOINT  USAGE?

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation in the works for commerce credits module.  Until it is committed you can preview it here: https://drupal.org/files/documentation-1629470-5.patch